# Unable to add to params hash using merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to get new values added my my params hash. I'm trying to add this `actor_id` key to params but this isn't working:

```
params.merge(:actor_id => 2)
```

When I use logger.debug before and after the merge I don't see my `actor_id` key. How do I add to `params`?

Comment: `merge` doesn't mutate the Hash.

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks, Justin. How would I go about adding to params?

Comment: In many cases, you can add a bang (`!`) to mutate the value. In this case, `merge!` will modify the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

> params.merge!(actor_id: 2)

it will modify the params itself as we are using the !

Answer (score 1):

This is because the method merge in [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) does not modify the receiver but rather returns a new hash with indifferent access with the result of the merge.

As the comments have suggested use merge! or use update which is an alias.

[ActiveController::Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) inherits from ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

```
    # This method has the same semantics of +update+, except it does not
    # modify the receiver but rather returns a new hash with indifferent
    # access with the result of the merge.
    def merge(hash, &block)
      self.dup.update(hash, &block)
    end
```